# Removing SurveyMonkey branding on closing collector, when using the API?

Tags: api, surveymonkey

When using the `PATCH /collectors/{id}` endpoint to close a collector, there seems to be no option to remove the SurveyMonkey branding.

I have tired setting is_branding_enabled, but I get a `400`, with the message:

> Invalid schema in the body provided.

We are on the Enterprise plan.

Answer (score 0):

What type of collector is it? For email collector, you can set is_branding_enabled to false on the message. For weblink collector, You need to set footer to false on `/surveys/{id}` endpoint.

Comment: It's an email collector. This is different from the invite message branding. This is branding on the "Survey is closed" page.

Comment: Disable branding on "Survey is closed" page is not available to the api right now. :(